# I need help with an average question

Tags: arithmetic

My brother and I are going on vacation. We need to rent a car. We will rent the car for $10$ days. However, I will only be on the vacation for $5$ days. My  brother will be on vacation for the full $10$ days. The cost of the car is $£600$. How much should he pay and how much should I pay?

Comment: $600 per day or for the 10 days?

Comment: $600 for the 10 days

Answer (score 2):

You are paying $60$ for every day you own the car. For the first $5$ days, you pay $300$ and split the bill, meaning you pay $150$, for the second $5$ days, your brother pays the whole $300.$

Answer (score 0):

You could think of this in terms of 'man-days' - one man-day is when one man is on holiday for one day. How many man-days are there in your holiday? Now try and share the cost of the car across all man-days and scale up according to how many man-days your and your brother each contribute.

Answer (score -2):

You will be on vacation for 5 days, and your brother for 10. So the total amount of vacation days is 15. Split the price (600) over the number of days (15) to get 40 pounds per day. Therefore, you pay 200 while your brother pays 400.

Comment: Not true. He will only be using the car half the time for the $5$ days. The rent for the $5$ days is $300$, so he should pay $150$. Or in other ways, you should count how many half days each brother gets the car. OP uses the car for $5$ half days, while his brother uses it for $5$ half days during the first $5$ days and $10$ half-days during the second $5$ days, meaning one should pay $\frac{5}{20}$ of the price and the other $\frac{15}{20}$.